# Bundle Config does not work in release mode

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a .NET MVC project. I manage all .css and .js file in my BundleConfig file.
It's work great in locally debug mode. But when I run this project release mode , 
make all the JavaScript files with the bundle like;

```
<script src="/bundles/alljquery?v=UzNlCXfliUxnARi00NzVdOS0lml6av0Kte2hPdkLmLw1"></script>
```

I saw this line in my DOM but it does not work. For example I write a alert in a function it does not work.

I looked for a sample JavaScript line in the bundle and found it. so it actually loads the file. But I did not see alert or another actions.

This is my RegisterBundles method;

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            #if !DEBUG
              BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
            #endif
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Sitecss").IncludeDirectory("~/Content/css", "*.css",true)); 

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/alljquery").IncludeDirectory("~/Content/js", "*.js", true));

            var jsFiles = Directory.GetFiles(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Content/Pages"), "*.js");
            foreach (var jsFile in jsFiles)
            {
                var bundleName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(jsFile);
                bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jsMrT/" + bundleName).Include(
                "~/Content/pages/" + Path.GetFileName(jsFile)));
            }


        }
```

I try this ;

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

And I try this;

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="BundleModule" />
        <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

How can I solved it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all javascript methods are interlaced and duplicate, so I close the bundle and add all scripts layout a manual.This may be from the libraries I use.

Answer (score 1):

Add into the web config.

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
     <compilation debug="true" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thanks, but in release mode ie deployed I want to solve this problem. it works already in debug mode